# Plotly contour subplots each having their own colorbar

Tags: python, plotly, contour, colorbar

I am trying to generate contours using Plotly. There are 5 contours which I am plotting in a 5x1 grid using subplots. I am unable to see an option by which I can have a separate colorbar for each contour subplot. For line plots I can use 
shared_xaxes or shared_yaxes options, but unable to find documentation where I can have a separate colorbar for each subplot in this 5x1 grid.

Here are some reference links I tried to go through:

https://plot.ly/python/contour-plots/

https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps-contours-and-2dhistograms-tutorial/

https://plot.ly/python/reference/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each subplot does in fact have its own colorbar. The issue is that by default they are plotted on top of each other so it's hard to tell there are several of them. By setting the `len` and `y` parameters of the colorbar, you can space them out and see how they are associated with each contour. Here's an example, loosely based on the Plotly [contour docs](https://plot.ly/python/contour-plots/):

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
cbarlocs = [.85, .5, .15]
zmax = [2, 5, 10]

for n in range(3):
    trace = go.Contour(
            z=[[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
               [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
               [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
               [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
               [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]], 
            colorbar=dict(len=0.25, y=cbarlocs[n]), 
            zmin=0, zmax=zmax[n])

    fig.append_trace(trace, n+1, 1)

plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

The crucial part is `colorbar=dict(len=0.25, y=cbarlocs[n])`. This code results in something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dan, if one of plot is bar chart, how to customize colorbar location for bar chart? bar chart doesn't have parameter of colorbar= Thanks